# How to create a lagom server with grpc service implementation only?

Tags: scala, grpc, lagom, akka-grpc

I am trying to create a grpc service using Lagom framework following this [documentation](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/lagom-scala-grpc-example/). Here the `hello` service also exposes rest API besides grpc service.

Now while creating lagom server in the ApplicationLoader we assign grpc service impl as `additionalRouter` like so:

```
abstract class HelloApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with AhcWSComponents {

  // Bind the service that this server provides
  override lazy val lagomServer =
    serverFor[HelloService](wire[HelloServiceImpl])
    .additionalRouter(wire[HelloGrpcServiceImpl])

}
```

Its all fine for the purpose of demo but we may not need to always create a REST endpoint besides gRPC endpoint. In that case I won't need either `HelloService` or `HelloServiceImpl`. The problem is how would you create lagom server with only `HelloGrpcServiceImpl`? I can't see to find a way either any documentation or the APIs itself to be able to achieve this!

Please suggest.

Comment: Probably an answer! I asked similar question on lagom discussion forum 2 years ago. LOL!

https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/how-to-write-lagom-managed-service-that-dont-expose-rest-endpoints/5585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer in the link I provided as a comment to my question, the solution would look something like this:

```
trait PrimeGeneratorService extends Service {
  override def descriptor: Descriptor = named("prime-generator")
}

class PrimeGeneratorServiceImpl() extends PrimeGeneratorService

abstract class PrimeGeneratorApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context) with AhcWSComponents {

  override lazy val lagomServer: LagomServer = {
    serverFor[PrimeGeneratorService](wire[PrimeGeneratorServiceImpl])
      .additionalRouter(wire[PrimeGeneratorGrpcServiceImpl])
  }

}

class PrimeGeneratorLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {
  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new PrimeGeneratorApplication(context) {
      override def serviceLocator: ServiceLocator = NoServiceLocator
    }

  override def loadDevMode(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new PrimeGeneratorApplication(context) with LagomDevModeComponents

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[PrimeGeneratorService])
}
```

Here we have to create dummy service trait and implementation, namely, `PrimeGeneratorService` and `PrimeGeneratorServiceImpl`, respectively.

Don't forget to add following in the loader class:

```
override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[PrimeGeneratorService])
```